# Checking for repeating values within a sting & add extra penalty time

Tags: vb.net

let's say i have a sequence of alphabet, **A,A,B,C,B,D,D**

Each Alphabet repeating an employee, with an time given to them to complete a task.

- A - 3.5hours
- B - 5hours
- C - 2hours
- D - 2.2hours

Everytime I have to add up the total time, which I have no problem doing so.

**A,A,B,C,B,D,D = 3.5 + 3.5 + 5 + 2 + 5 + 2.2 + 2.2**

However, the problem i'm facing now is **If one worker carry out another task immediately, i have to add an extra 3.5hours of penalty**. Lets say A,A. it means that Worker A have to do the next task directly without any rest. thus a penalty must be added is same values repeated. i'm trying to put A as my first value, then compare with my next value. after that replace it with the next value and continue checking till the end. i have tried writing out some codes, however it seems to be looping endlessly.

```
'display all my random values as string
Dim RandomString = String.Join((","), RandomEmployee.ToArray())

' Check for dups
                Dim First As String
                Dim Second As String

                First = InStr(RandomString, (","))
                While First <> ""
                    If First = Second Then
                        Dim penalty As Integer = 3.5
                        RandomTimeTaken.Add(penalty)
                    Else
                        Second = First
                    End If

                End While

LblRandom1.Text = RandomString
```

RandomEmployee is an Array which store all my employee. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by this statement "**If one worker carry out another task immediately**"?

Comment: @MarkHall it's like A,A. it repeated. meaning worker A completed his task, and he have to do the next task directly.

Comment: You need to adjust the RandomString variable each iteration of the loop. I think you would not consider the last element in your code. I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the `First` from `RandomString` each iteration of the loop. But you can solve your problem using `List` instead.

```
Dim RandomString = String.Join((","), RandomEmployee.ToArray())
Dim ListEmp as List(Of String) = RandomEmployee.ToList()

If ListEmp.Count > 1 then
    For aux as integer = 0 to ListEmp.Count - 2
        Dim First as String = ListEmp(aux)
        Dim Second as String = ListEmp(aux+1)
        If First = Second then  
             RandomTimeTaken.Add(3.5)
        End If
    Next
End IF
LblRandom1.Text = RandomString
```